# HTML/JS Popup Form Submit New Window

Tags: javascript, html

I apologize if my explanations are bad, I'm fairly new to coding...

I'm currently using a code on a website building site called Clickfunnels.

This is how the code works:

When I click the submit button, the form submits, redirects to another site on the current tab, while simultaneously opening a new tab to a different destination.

The code is this:

```
<form action="LINK GOES HERE" target="_blank">
   <a href="#"></a>
</form>
<script>
   $('a').click(function () {
       // do something you want ...
       $('form').form-popup();
   });
</script>
```

(I'm not sure what the "do something you want..." is, I found this code on this site somewhere...)

So my problem is this:

There's a website I'm trying to build where the form does not appear on the initial page... There's a popup form that opens when you click the button...

From that popup form, you click, it submits the form and redirects you to another page on the current tab.

I'm trying to use this code to simultaneously open a new tab, just like before, but there's a problem... whenever I click the button for the popup to appear, instead of the popup appearing, it refreshes or brings me back to the first page, and opens a new tab, WITHOUT submitting the form.

What code do I have to add so that when I click the button, the popup form appears... when I submit the form, it submits, redirects me to another page on the current tab, while simultaneously opening a new tab to another destination?

Your help would be greatly appreciated...

Thank you in advanced.

**** EDIT ****

I'm SO sorry... I wrote the initial code wrong.

It's:

```
<form action="LINK GOES HERE" target="_blank">

   <a href="#"></a>
</form>
<script>
   $('a').click(function () {
       // do something you want ...
       $('form').submit();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

idk if that will help or not , maybe use preventDefault() method , on the callBack function , to prevent the page from refreshing if this is the problem

so

```
   <script>
       $('a').click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault()
           // do something you want ...
           $('form').form-popup();
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: sorry sir... i wrote the intial code wrong... please see edit.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is right, but targeting `a` is wishful thinking unless you only have a single link on the page

Comment: well, it's a button that opens a popup that has only 1 link...

Comment: so the above code give by juvian3211 does what i would like it to... in the beginning.
i can click the button and the popup shows up with the form.
the weird problem is... when submitting the form, the page refreshes back to the original page, and when i click again to show the popup, it then opens a new tab to direct me to another page, but the original page does not redirect.